# How can I pass arguent rule of aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration as variable using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

Using terraform version 1.0.10 and AWS provider 4, My code deploy an AWS s3 bucket using a module that has aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration as required and works fine:

main.tf code:

```
  source                = "./modules/aws_plain_resource/s3/"
  bucket_name           = var.bucket_name_cloud_events
  sse_algorithm         = var.sse_algorithm
  logging_target_bucket = var.logging_target_bucket
  lifecycle_status      = "Enabled"
  first_period          = 30
  fp_storage_class      = "STANDARD_IA"
  second_period         = 0
  sp_storage_class      = "GLACIER"
  object_expiration     = 1060
  common_tags = {
    data_classification = "confidential"
    risk_classification = "high"
    tyro_team           = "operations_team"
  }
}
```

Module code:

```
  bucket = var.bucket_name

   tags = merge(var.common_tags, {
    "Name" = var.bucket_name
  })
}
  resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "this" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.this.id
  acl    = "private"
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "this" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.this.id
  rule {
    apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
      kms_master_key_id = var.kms_master_key_arn
      sse_algorithm     = var.sse_algorithm
    }
  }
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "this" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.this.id

  rule {
    id     = "iac_lifecycle_rule"
    status = var.lifecycle_status
    transition {
      days          = var.first_period
      storage_class = var.fp_storage_class
    }

    transition {
      days          = var.second_period
      storage_class = var.sp_storage_class
    }

    expiration {
      days = var.object_expiration
    }
  }
}
output "bucket-id" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket.this.id
}
```

However, I would like to leave the argument rule in the maint.tf file to be configurable. Is there a way to pass the rule configuration as variable to the terraform S3 module?

Rule is:

```
rule {
    id     = "iac_lifecycle_rule"
    status = var.lifecycle_status
    transition {
      days          = var.first_period
      storage_class = var.fp_storage_class
    }

    transition {
      days          = var.second_period
      storage_class = var.sp_storage_class
    }

    expiration {
      days = var.object_expiration
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a `rule` map variable in your module, and then pass it in:

```
module "bucket"
  source                = "./modules/aws_plain_resource/s3/"
  rule = {
    id     = "iac_lifecycle_rule"
    status = var.lifecycle_status
    transition = {
      days          = var.first_period
      storage_class = var.fp_storage_class
    }

    transition = {
      days          = var.second_period
      storage_class = var.sp_storage_class
    }

    expiration = {
      days = var.object_expiration
    }
  }
```

and then you have to explicitly set all the values in `aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration`:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "this" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.this.id

  rule {
    id     = rule["id"]
    status = rule["status"]
    transition {
      days          = rule["transition"]["days"] 
      storage_class = rule["transition"]["storage_class"] 
    }

    #  and so on for the rest

  }
}
```

Comment: Does not work for me. TF complain about map since it needs to contain elements of the same type. status = str & days = int

Comment: @Sallyerik Sadly I don't know what it complains about. You haven't provided any error message, nor the actual new version of your TF code that you are using.